# Rails 4 dynamic has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A `workout` has_many `movements`.

A `result` belongs_to a `user`, `workout` and an optional `modified_workout`

`result` model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :workout
has_many :movements, through: :workout
belongs_to :modified_workout, class_name: "Workout"
```

Right now on my `user` model:

```
has_many :workouts, through: :results
has_many :movements, through: :workouts
```

However, I want to incorporate `modified_workout` in to the `user`'s `has_many :movements`. If a `modified_workout` relation exists, I want to return only those `movements` that `belong_to` the `modified_workout`. `Movements` that `belong_to` `workout` should **not** be returned. if `modified_workout` relation does not exist (i.e. the `modified_workout_id` column is `null`) then return `movements` that belong to `workout`.

Something like

```
has_many :movements -> 
  if modified_workout
    return modified_workout.movements 
  else 
    return workout.movements
```

but as a `scope` that operates on all `results` that `belong_to` that `user`.

Comment: What is it that makes a workout modified? What is the database column that changes between regular and modified?

Comment: Or does a result have two keys? `modified_workout_id` and `workout_id`, both of which point at the `Workout` table?

Comment: @LannyBose Result has two keys, both pointing at the Workout table. `workout_id` can never be null, `modified_workout_id` can be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is maybe over-doing it, and it does get us to the goal of being able to call a straight-up...

```
User.movements
```

I'm creating a scope on `Workout` that filters out any workouts that have been overridden.

In `User`, I'm creating a new association (`original_workouts`) which uses that scope to get `original_movements`.

The biggest downside is that by using addition of two Active Record Associations, it becomes an array, which prevents subsequent scoping.

**workout.rb**

```
class Workout
  has_many :movements

  has_many :results_as_original, class_name: 'Result', foreign_key: 'workout_id'
  has_many :results_as_modified, class_name: 'Result', foreign_key: 'modified_workout_id'

  scope :original_and_not_overridden, -> { 
    joins(:results_as_original).where("results.modified_workout_id IS NULL")
  }
```

**result.rb**

```
class Result
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :modified_workout
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
  has_many :results
  has_many :original_workouts, ->{ original_and_not_overridden }, 
                               through: :results, source: :workouts
  has_many :modified_workouts, through: results
  has_many :original_movements, through: :workouts, source: :movements
  has_many :modified_workout_movements, through: :modified_workouts

  def movements
      (original_workout_movements + modified_workout_movements).uniq
  end
```

An alternative way to define movements is to requery using the list of ids. This would return a Relation and allow further scoping. Potentially a performance loss there?

```
class User
  def movements
    ids = original_workout_movements.pluck(:id) + modified_workout_movements.pluck(:id)
    Movement.where(id: ids)
  end
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. Do you think it would be more performant to modify your User.movements method to have the SQL database directly look up the relevant IDs (e.g. 'WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)" or something similar) and hence just perform one query?

Comment: Potentially, but it will only be one (or two?) additional query per User. If you're planning on showing an index view of users that counts all their movements, that might get expensive...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `has_many` relationship with `movement`, as you are just accessing movements of workout or modified_workout.

You can add a `movement` method in your `result` (or in your `user`) from there you can access movements something like following:

```
@result=Result.find(id)
@result.movements() # returns either modified_workout or 
                  #  workout.movements depending on situation
or
@user=User.find(id)
@user.result.movements()
```

And `movements` method would look like following:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   # belong_to and has_many logics goes here
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :workout
   belongs_to :modified_workout, class_name: "Workout"

   def movements
      unless self.modified_workout.nil?
          return self.modified_workout.movements 
      else 
          return self.workout.movements
      end
   end
end
```

If that does not work then a clever implementation of polymorphic association might help.

Comment: It should just be `def movements` if it's an instance method.

Comment: And a user doesn't have a `modified_workout`. A `Result` does.

Comment: updated my answer, taking your remarks in account @LannyBose.

Comment: Not sure I see how this allows me to see all movements for a given user?